# How to embed php code within jpgraph page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jpgraph

below is my jp graph code

```
            include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph.php");
            include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph_scatter.php");

            // Some data for the points
            $datax = array(3.5,13.7,3,4,6.2,6,3.5,8,14,8,11.1,13.7);
            $datay = array(10,22,12,13,17,20,16,19,30,31,40,43);

            // A new scatter graph
            $graph = new Graph(300,200,'auto');
            $graph->SetShadow();
            $graph->SetScale("linlin");

            //$graph->img->SetMargin(40,40,40,40);        

            $graph->title->Set("Scatter plot with Image Map");
            $graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

            // Client side image map targets
            $targ=array("pie_csimex1.php#1","pie_csimex1.php#2","pie_csimex1.php#3",
            "pie_csimex1.php#4","pie_csimex1.php#5","pie_csimex1.php#6",
            "pie_csimex1.php#7","pie_csimex1.php#8","pie_csimex1.php#9" );

            // Strings to put as "alts" (and "title" value)
            $alts=array("val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d");

            // Create a new scatter plot
            $sp1 = new ScatterPlot($datay,$datax);

            // Use diamonds as markerss
            $sp1->mark->SetType(MARK_DIAMOND);
            $sp1->mark->SetWidth(10);

            // Set the scatter plot image map targets
            $sp1->SetCSIMTargets($targ,$alts);

            // Add the plot
            $graph->Add($sp1);

            // Send back the HTML page which will call this script again
            // to retrieve the image.
            $graph->StrokeCSIM();
```

above code works fine by displaying the scattered graph... but i want to embed some php code in the same page ,if i do that it does not work.... as per some expert's advice i replaced 
`$graph->StrokeCSIM();`

with 
                `$fileName = "./lang/12345.png";
                $graph->img->Stream($fileName);

```
            echo('<img src="./lang/12345.png" />');`
```

it creates a file with 12345.png and does not display graph... how can i fix this?

updated question with code....

```
            $_GET['Variance']=$Variance;
            $_GET['Emp_RecFactor']=$Emp_RecFactor;


            // Some data for the points
            $datax =$Emp_RecFactor;
            $datay =$Variance;



            // A new scatter graph
            $graph = new Graph(600,600);
            $graph->SetScale('intlin',-10,10,0,100);
            $graph->yscale->ticks->Set(1);
            $graph->xscale->ticks->Set(5);

            //$graph->img->SetMargin(40,40,40,40);        

             $graph->xaxis->title->Set("Reco-Factor");
            $graph->yaxis->title->Set("Variance");
            $graph->title->Set("Equity Graph Of All Employees");
            $graph->title->SetFont(FF_FONT1,FS_BOLD);

            // Client side image map targets
            $targ=array("pie_csimex1.php#1","pie_csimex1.php#2","pie_csimex1.php#3",
            "pie_csimex1.php#4","pie_csimex1.php#5","pie_csimex1.php#6",
            "pie_csimex1.php#7","pie_csimex1.php#8","pie_csimex1.php#9" );

            // Strings to put as "alts" (and "title" value)
            $alts=array("val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d","val=%d");

            // Create a new scatter plot
            $sp1 = new ScatterPlot($datay,$datax);

            // Use diamonds as markerss
            $sp1->mark->SetType(MARK_DIAMOND);
            $sp1->mark->SetWidth(10);

            // Set the scatter plot image map targets
            $sp1->SetCSIMTargets($targ,$alts);

            // Add the plot
            $graph->Add($sp1);

            // Send back the HTML page which will call this script again
            // to retrieve the image.



            $graph->Strokecsim();
```

test2.php contains...

```
            echo "<p>hello</p>";
            include "Talent_Graphcopy.php"; // containing the graph code
            echo "<p>goodbye</p>";
```

Comment: Is there any data contained within 12345.png (i.e. not a zero-byte file?)

Comment: it shows as '1kb'...iam getting graph background white ... but not graph..

Comment: No headers, legends or anything, just pure white?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$graph->StrokeCSIM() produces a graph in the form of an image map. The PHP that contains this code (lets call it the graph script) is capable of generating both the supporting HTML and the graph image itself.

When the graph script is called without parameters (e.g. http://contoso.com/graph.php), HTML is generated. The HTML generated contains an IMG tag that points to the script itself with a magic parameter (e.g. `<img src="graph.php?_jpg_csimd=1"` ). When the script is called with the magic parameter, an image is generated.

You cannot put in PHP code that produces HTML output into the graph script as it will prevent the image generation functionality from working correctly. If you want to mix your custom HTML with the graph output, you can include the graph script in another PHP script.

e.g. Display.php

```
echo "<p>hello</p>";
include "Talent_Graphcopy.php"; // containing the graph code
echo "<p>goodbye</p>";
```

Talent_Graphcopy.php

```
// fancy graph code...
$graph->StrokeCSIM("Talent_Graphcopy.php");
```

Specify the name of the graph script as an argument for StrokeCSIM. It tells the script to set the IMG SRC to point to the graph script itself for generating the graph. If you do not specify it, the IMG SRC will point to Display.php... which is wrong, because the browser will ask Display.php for the image, which it is obviously not capable of providing.

Comment: it works if there are no $targ or $alts.. please check this [link](http://www.asial.co.jp/jpgraph/demo/src/Examples/show-example.php?target=scatter_csimex1.php) am trying to use that code... it creates and displays image but mouse over or pop up[ will not work.... any ways to fix that?

Comment: I really appreciate the way you are trying to help me.. but iam bit confused... bcos if i use  $graph->StrokeCSIM('./lang/12345.png');in test.php it does not create any image...:(

Comment: In this case using StrokeCSIM without parameters $graph->StrokeCSIM(); as before

Comment: k but if i use it without parameters then where will it generate image?i tried using it without parameter .. please check my updated question(code).... but it does not work....

Comment: Can you confirm that the code block you first posted (closest to the top) does work (i.e. you can see the image and the mouseover stuff?) If that is working code, save it as test2.php, include it in another PHP and try again.

Comment: AND remember include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph.php");
            include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph_scatter.php"); inside test2.php

Comment: yes mouseover stuffs works when run the file.. but it does not work when i include in another php...yes i have included include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph.php"); here is my tst2.php code include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph.php");
include_once ("jpgraph/jpgraph_scatter.php");
echo "<p>hello</p>";
include("Test.php");
echo "<p>goodbye</p>"; hmmm i think its my bad luck.....

Comment: hmmm it worked after i removed echo hello and goodbye... but again if i include any external php code in test.php it does not create any images as earlier :(

Comment: I think its the famous HTTP headers problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487796/jpgraph-error-http-headers-have-already-been-sent for more ideas

Comment: thanks for the link but i have checked that.. it works for stroke() but does not work if we use strokecsim()... any ways to fix strokecsim()???

Comment: See edited answer! I tested this out and made it work. Sorry I misled you earlier re the parameter for StrokeCSIM() - it is indeed very important.

Comment: i really appreciate your effort dear...but this did not fix my problem... actually my problem was ,,, i want to use foreach loop in 'Talent_Graphcopy.php' but if i use any statement/code other then jpgraph ,it will not accept it will not display any image.. thats the reason i tried to save the image in my local dir(using stroke()) and displayed it which worked fine but if i want mouse over feature i have to use strokecsim() its again i can not use any foreach loops/or not even a echo statements in Talent_Graphcopy.php.. :(

Comment: OK I see what you mean. Does your foreach loop produce any form of output? Like I mentioned in the answer even if you echo one character the image generation will fail.

Comment: i really appreciate the way you are trying to help me dear... well what ever the data we put inside graph file it does not work, but the good thing is i have fixed this issue by merging other class files in "jp graph class file...",so right now problem has been resolved,i dont think thats the right solution...:)