# JpGraph php graph library - trouble embedding graph

Tags: php, jpgraph

I have managed to create a graph using JpGraph, I want to now take it a step further and embed this graph in my template/view php file.

So I put the graph code into a seperate php file to then embed however, when I try to embed it via
`<embed src="templates/ctl008/graphshow.php" height=80em; width=160em;> </embed>` it leaves me with a `requested URL not found` error. 
I have fiddled with the path and tried just: `graphshow.php`, `ctl008/graphshow.php` and other such variations. Is it my path that is not correct or is there something else I am missing? I have also tried to embed it with `<img src="graphshow.php" />` .
 A funny quirk is when I turn on `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and try to view the graph on its own I am left with an error message: `JpGraph Error: HTTP headers have already been sent. Caused by output from file gd_image.inc.php at line 92.`  but if i turn off the `error_reporting` it displays the graph as expected.
 I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction with this :)

Here is my `graphshow.php` file:

```
<?php require_once ('../library/include/jpgraph/src/jpgraph.php');
require_once ('../library/include/jpgraph/src/jpgraph_line.php');
require_once ('../library/include/jpgraph/src/jpgraph_bar.php');
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);
$gasArray = array();
foreach($searchArray as $gArray){
    $gasArray[] = $gArray['GASVB'];
}
$stromArray = array();
foreach($searchArray as $sArray){
    $stromArray[] = $sArray['STROVB'];
}
$olArray = array(); 
foreach($searchArray as $oArray){
    $olArray[] = $oArray['OLVB'];
}

 if(!empty($gasArray) || !empty($stromArray) || !empty($olArray)){
     ob_end_clean();
 $width= 1200;
 $height = 400;
 $graph = new Graph($width, $height);
 $graph->SetScale('intint');
 
 $graph->title->Set('Energie Verbrauch');
 $graph->SetMargin(80,25,30,80);
 
 $graph->xaxis->title->Set('Datum');
 $graph->yaxis->title->Set('Verbrauch');
 // print_r($dateArray);
 
 $lineGas = new LinePlot($gasArray);
 $lineGas->SetLegend('Gas');
 $lineStrom = new LinePlot($stromArray);
 $lineStrom->SetLegend('Strom');
 $lineOl = new LinePlot($olArray);
 $lineOl->SetLegend('ÖL');
 
 $graph->Add($lineGas);
 $graph->Add($lineStrom);
 $graph->Add($lineOl);
 $graph->Stroke();
 }
?>
```

Comment: Hey Ken, in the seperate `showgraph.php` file, or in the file I am trying to embed the graph in? Again, if I remove the `ini_set(etc.etc.)` the graph displays on its own

Comment: Hey ken I was just about to post an answer :) thanks for the comments though, appreciate it

Comment: Great to know that you solved the problem. Have a nice day and happy coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to start off with a few helpful links: 
[JpGraph Error: HTTP headers have already been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487796/jpgraph-error-http-headers-have-already-been-sent) 
http://www.digialliance.com/docs/jpgraph/html/2210intro.html 
https://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/jpgraph-graph-charts-plots-php 
https://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch05s05.html 
 
now that that is out of the way, how I managed to get it working: 
Starting with the advice/help in the above [StackOverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487796/jpgraph-error-http-headers-have-already-been-sent)  I turned my seperate php file into a `function` the final line of my `graphshow.php` function was this: `$graph->Stroke("charts/graphEnergy.png");` where `charts` is the folder I am saving in and `graphEnergy.png` is the name of the file being saved. 
then in my `view/template` page I `require_once('chart/ctl008/graphshow.php');` made my php file accessible, called my function like so `generateGraph($gasArray, $stromArray, $olArray);`
 and then in the html section embedded the graph with `<img src="./charts/graphEnergy.png" />` 
 
What **really** tripped me up was needing to call the `graph.png` with the `./` before the `charts/graphEnergy.php`, and then  I was able to display my bootiful graph on my `view/template` page.
 I hope this helps someone in the future :)

- BoogaBooga

Comment: I can also recommend `LibChart` as a php graphing alternative to `JpGraph` https://naku.dohcrew.com/libchart/pages/samplecode/ :)